# Calabash iOS: Setting location does not work

Tags: xcode, calabash, calabash-ios

I am using set_location on Calabash iOS 0.9.169, but it does not seem to take effect.
This has worked earlier and I think might have broken after upgrading to 0.9.169.

I am using:

```
set_location(latitude: latitude.to_f,longitude: longitude.to_f)
```

But the simulator still reports either no location, or the location selected in Debug -> Location, if one is set there.

Is this a known issue ? Any workarounds or things to try ? I have debugged through the Ruby code and the uia call to set location succeeds.

Version info:

```
~> calabash-ios version
0.9.169
~> xcodebuild -version
Xcode 5.1.1
Build version 5B1008

Calabash framework version: 0.9.169
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE FOR Xcode 7** Setting the location is broken for iOS Simulators *and* physical devices.

I recently investigated this issue.

I can confirm that setting the location works in iOS 7 Simulators, but does not work on physical devices.

We are tracking this issue here:  https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/377